# Jetty and tomcat doesn't load implementation of AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: spring, maven, model-view-controller, tomcat, jetty

I have Spring 3.2 application with a pure java based configuration.
When I start the application with "mvn jetty:run" everything works fine.
But when I deploy a war file in Jetty(9.0.2) or Tomcat(7.0) the webapp from my war-file is deployed, but it only serves my static assets (index.html) but doesn't load my Config-classes. It seems, that my implementation of AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer is not loaded.

Is there a special configuration-flag to enable the scanning of this files?

Comment: Please detail your webapp setup.  where is your implementation of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` found in your webapp?  as a class in the `WEB-INF/classes` or in a jar found in `WEB-INF/lib`?  Also how are you referencing it? in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` (if so, lets see your web.xml), via Servlet 3.0 annotations, or via some Spring mechanism?

Comment: my `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`-Implementation is in `WEB-INF/classes` not in a referenced lib. My `web.xml` is almost empty:

except the XML header (with `version="3.0"` and `metadata-complete="false"` and a Taglib definition.
I'm not referencing my Impl. of `Abstr...` in my web.xml.

Comment: Here is my `web.xml` https://gist.github.com/tarator/5438248#file-gistfile1-txt As mentioned: this configuration works fine with mvn-jetty-plugin. My `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` has no special annotation.

Comment: I DID IT: Annotations were not enabled in jetty: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/annotations.html#annotations-quick-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was, that annotations were not enabled in my Jetty-Standalone Configuration: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/annotations.html#annotations-quick-setup

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `metadata-complete` in web.xml is true. After replacing that with false, `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` is called